# SVG shapes are invisible in Internet Explorer

Tags: svg

I am working on shapes with SVG: rectangle shape . The problem is in IE where the shape is invisible.

For Firefox :

```
<rect matrix="1,0,0,1,320,100" invmatrix="1,0,0,1,-320,-100" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,320,100)" stroke="rgb(0,0,255)" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="0.5" fill="rgb(200,230,255)" fill-opacity="0.3764705882352941" width="100" height="30" rx="10" ry="10">
```

on IE:

```
<rect matrix="1,0,0,1,320,100" invmatrix="1,0,0,1,-320,-100" transform="matrix(1,0,0,1,320,100)" stroke="rgb(0,0,0)" stroke-opacity="0" stroke-width="0" fill="rgb(0,0,0)" fill-opacity="0" width="100" height="30" rx="10" ry="10">
```

The problem is caused by the attributes : `fill` and `stroke` !! 
How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: I regret to inform that you are not coding in JavaScript: you're apparently using a markup language called SVG (Scalable Vector Graphics). I've edited the question to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in the "IE" version of your markup you've specified a stroke-opacity of 0 and a fill-opacity of 0. This means that the stroke is entirely transparent and so is the fill which means the whole thing is invisible.

The "Firefox" version is opaque which is why you can see it.

Answer (score 0):

checking here http://validator.w3.org/ might be a good start
I'm not sure what the issue is but have you considered using a polyfill. 
http://raphaeljs.com may solve many issues when it comes to i.e